# Override svelte component's properties type

Tags: typescript, svelte

I know this isn't a normal use case for Svelte, but given any component of my application, they can all have a property I don't declare using `export let`.

For example,

*Hello.svelte*

```html
<script lang="ts">
  export let name;
</script>
<h1>Hello {name}</h1>
```

*Goodbye.svelte*

```html
<script lang="ts">
  export let name;
</script>
<h1>Goodbye {name}</h1>
```

*App.svelte*

```html
<script lang="ts">
  import Hello from './Hello.svelte';
  import Goodbye from './Goodbye.svelte';
</script>
<Hello name="john" special-prop={true} />
<Goodbye name="jack" special-prop={false}  />
```

`typescript` and `svelte-check` reports obviously `special-prop`.
How can I override the `SvelteComponent` type, in order to accept something like

```
special-prop?: boolean;
```

Comment: May I ask for some context, why would you want this feature?

Comment: The context is an app with custom partial hydration using a special property (ie, we differentiate hydration based on that prop), but yeah, now there's sveltekit...

Answer (score 2):

There's a special interface `$$Props` that you can declare for this use case.

**Hello.svelte**

```html
<script lang="ts">
export let name: string;
interface $$Props {
  name: string
  "special-prop"?: boolean
  [key: string]: any   // optional, to further loosen up props constraint
}
</script>
```

References:

- https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/issues/442
- https://github.com/dummdidumm/rfcs/blob/ts-typedefs-within-svelte-components/text/ts-typing-props-slots-events.md

Comment: The property can also be extracted to an interface which then `$$Props` can be extended from.

Comment: @H.B. Related, do you know a way to avoid repeating `name: string`?

Comment: Unfortunately no, see also [this comment](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/issues/442#issuecomment-1374775494).

Comment: But this has to be done inside a component. I'd like to declare it globally, so that every component accepts it.

Comment: @krampstudio: I tried to find a solution that applies globally; currently that does not appear to be possible. (Maybe someone else finds something though...)